# Styling textarea's "required" attribute with CSS doesn't work

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea, required

I have added my inputs, name, email etc. with the `required` attribute and provided through CSS, icons that signify invalidated/validated status perfectly. However, the same styling will not insert the icons in the two textareas of my form?

I have seen that I should remove all whitespace between the tags, I am sure I have, but it didn't solve it.

```
<form id="from">
  <table width="742" border="0">
    <caption>
    <h1>Your details</h1>
    <br>
    </caption>
  <tr>
    <td width="117">First Name</td>
    <td width="161"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="" required></td>
    <td width="29">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="242">Date of Birth</td>
    <td width="171"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="eg. 01/05/1975" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surname</td>

    <td><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="" required></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td rowspan="4"><textarea rows="5" class="input-mini" placeholder="Full Postal Address" required></textarea></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input class="input-small" type="email" placeholder="e.g. you@your.mail" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Email- Again</td>
    <td><input class="input-small" type="email" placeholder="again" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Emergency Contact</td>
    <td rowspan="3"><textarea name="emergency" rows="5" placeholder="Emergency" required="required"></textarea>
&nbsp;      &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postcode</td>
    <td><input class="input-small1" type="text" placeholder="WA1 3DE"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> Option
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> Option
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> Option
</label>

</form>
```

The CSS is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#from  {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}
.input-small1 {
    width: 60px;
}
body {
    background-color:#BAFCFA;
}
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
input:required:valid {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-submit-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

I have applied the same rules to all the other inputs that I have with the textarea to no avail.

Comment: your question is a bit vague. Can you please specify what exactly is the problem you are facing? What result you are expecting?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really setup to test this but I am fairly certain this should solve your problem. The reason that it's not working on the textarea are because your css is only looking for input tags and not textarea tags. You should add it where you have `input:valid` and `input:invalid`

```
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid, 
textarea:required:invalid, textarea:focus:invalid {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

input:required:valid,
textarea:required:valid {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    background-position: right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't know where I should post this message, but your answer worked immediately. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think a comment on my answer is the appropriate area :) If it worked please mark my answer as correct. Glad I could help out!